# Run an SQL Query from R Shiny by clicking on the input text box

Tags: mysql, sql, r, shiny

I have created a shiny App with a run button to run an sql query to retrieve data from mysql database. the Data so retrieved will act as the input of the R shiny

```
  library(DBI)
  library(bigrquery)
  library(readr)
  library(shiny)
```

The above step imports the libraries.

Next we create the database connection parameters

```
    project <- "A-dev"
    dataset <- "A_table"
    con <- dbConnect( bigrquery::bigquery(), project = project, dataset = 
    dataset)
```

Within the dataset, are a set of columns that contain the parameters we need to extract. The query used to extract these column values is as follows

```
query2 <- "select C_name from A_table group by 
C_name"
```

The above query will create a list of values to act as a drop down input selection in R shiny

The following is the structure of the App.

The UI of the shiny App is created as follows. The layout consists of a Run button to run the query, and a set of drop downs that will return the results of the query

```
   ui <- fluidPage(

   sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(actionButton(inputId = "Button", label = "run 
  Query"),uiOutput(outputId = "List1")),
   mainPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId = "Table1")) ))
```

The Server Part of the App is as follows

```
     server <- function(input, output, session) {

      ##### Here the Action button is connected
       my_data <- reactive({ 
       if(input$Button == 0)
       {return(0) }
       isolate({
       input$Button


    query2 <- "select C_name from A_table group by C_name"


      df <- query_exec(query2, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE, 
      max_pages = Inf)
      df })})

     #### HERE WE CREATE THE DROP DOWN MENU PART

    output$List1<-renderUI({ 
      my_data=my_data()
      choices<-unique(my_data) 
      #creates State select box object called in ui
        selectInput(inputId = "List1", #name of input
              label = "List1:", #label displayed in ui
              choices =choices, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selectize 
           = T) }) #default choice (not required)


      output$Table1<-renderDataTable({###CREATE TABLE OUTPUT
      data.frame(my_data()) })}
```

We now Run the App as follows

```
         shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When we press the run query button, the App runs and the drop down menu is filled dynamically from the sql database.

My question is : Is it possible to run the query by merely clicking the select drop down box. In this case the Run query button will be rendered redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky to test this without any dummy data but if I understand correctly please test the below:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    ##### Here the Action button is connected
    my_data <- reactiveVal({
            query2 <- "select C_name from A_table group by C_name"


            df <- query_exec(query2, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE, 
                             max_pages = Inf)
            df })

    #### HERE WE CREATE THE DROP DOWN MENU PART

    output$List1<-renderUI({ 
        my_data=my_data()
        choices<-unique(my_data) 
        #creates State select box object called in ui
        selectInput(inputId = "List1", #name of input
                    label = "List1:", #label displayed in ui
                    choices =choices, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selectize 
                    = T) #default choice (not required)})
    })

        output$Table1<-renderDataTable({###CREATE TABLE OUTPUT
            data.frame(my_data()) })}
```

Although this would run at start-up and you requested when selecting the dropdown so I may be misunderstanding your use case?

Comment: I SUppose It will Run Without any issues. Will Check Sir. Thank you